# Populating a graph by drag and drop

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2008, css

I wanted to know if there were any jquery/html or c# plugins that would help me do the following.

Drag an item from a data list that is populated from the database and drop it into an empty graph.  Then have the graph fill with the information that was dropped in.

Current working on a solution but having a difficult time with the populating of the graph.

Any solutions or suggestions would be great! Thanks.

ps. Cannot use css3 or html 5

Answer (score 0):

Sencha's framework Ext JS 4 might have what you're looking for. It has drag and drop functionality, a very good charting package and data binding backing.

It is built to take advantage of css3 and html5, but it should have some decent fallback functionality when certain features are missing, so it might not be a problem.